# How to use dot product to conduct objective function in gurobi-python?

Tags: python, numpy, gurobi

To ADM: Please DO NOT delete my questions, it is about the dot product in gurobi-python, not for numpy!!!

In the past, I used m.addvars to add decision variables.

My objective function is a large-scale summation, which needs to be run many times.

I find that the construction of the objective function takes a long time.

The code is as follows:

```
    import gurobipy
    M = gurobipy.Model()
    # set decision variables
    x = M.addVars(n, m, vtype=gurobipy.GRB.BINARY, name='x')
    # n and m are very large


    # set obj
    obj = gurobipy.quicksum(A[ii, jj] * x[ii, jj]
                            for ii in range(n)
                            for jj in range(m))
    # A is a dense matrix (ndarray), shaped like x
    M.setObjective(obj, sense=gurobipy.GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

How to optimize this code

I try to construct x as a matrix, like this

```
x = M.addMvar((n,m), vtype=gurobipy.GRB.BINARY, name='x')
```

but, when I try to make dot product between A and x, the python raise an error.

```
M.setObjective(A * x, sense=gurobipy,GRB.MAXIMIZE)  # now, the A is a numpy.matrix
```

How to rewrite this code without traversing the generated list

```
obj = gurobipy.quicksum(A[ii, jj] * x[ii, jj]
                        for ii in range(n)
                        for jj in range(m))
```

Comment: Please don't start a question with "Please don't delete this!" - In case previous posts have been deleted they have certainly not fulfilled the minimal requirements for a good question. See here for more info on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Posts are not deleted due to "mean moderators".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend, but my previous question was deleted without any notice.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with Gurobi matrix expressions, it assumes a canonical form like:

```
max c'x
    A x = b
    x >= 0
```

So while you can use Model.addMVar() with an arbitrary number of dimensions, [you must slice it into 1-dimension to create linear expressions](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addmvar.html). So either flatten your objective coefficients and x into 1-d arrays (vectors), take slices, or switch to ordinary Var objects and build the expressions algebraically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean I have no other way to create constraints other than loops?